# How to I trick Java RMI/JMX to be accessible from outside localhost without hardcoding the IP?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

How can I trick Java RMI to be accessible from outside localhost without hardcoding the IP ?

Comment: Why are you thinking that RMI isn't accessible from other hosts? Are you sure you're not confusing the RMI binding with your firewall rules?

Answer (score 0):

As it is impossible to make RMI to bind to 0.0.0.0 the solution is to detect the IP and use it.

I used the solution below on both Linux and OS X:

```
IP=$(ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p')
# if we have several IPs found, we pick the first one
for IP in $IP:
do
  break
done

CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8081 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=${IP} "
```

Obviously that's the insecure way to configure it, but you are free to tune it to fit your needs.

Comment: It isn't 'impossible to make RMI bind to 0.0.0.0'. That is exactly what it does by default. It is also irrelevant. -1